# If conditions for unknown range of number

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, if-statement

My code returns an image for every number .e.g `if x==0` then it will create an image and save it in a particular folder but the issue is numbers are from 0 to lets say up to infinity how do i avoid `multiple if conditions` in such problem.
Please ask if question is not clear.  Here i posted only two `if condition` but it is increasing.

```
Zero=np.zeros(shape=(100, 100),dtype=np.uint8)  
count=0
count1=0
for (x, y) in labels:
        component = uf.find(labels[(x, y)])
        labels[(x, y)] = component
        if labels[(x, y)]==0:
            Zero[y][x]=int(255)
            count=count+1
            if count<=32:
                continue
            elif count>32:
                Zeroth = Image.fromarray(Zero)
                Zeroth.save(os.path.join(dirs, file_+'_Zero.png'), 'png')
        if labels[(x, y)]==1:
            One[y][x]=int(255)
            count1=count1+1
            if count1<=32:
                continue
            elif count1>32:
                First = Image.fromarray(One)
                First.save(os.path.join(dirs, file_+'_First.png'),'png')
```

Comment: why do you need an `if` at all? the code inside looks the same so can't you remove the conditions (make `First = Image.fromarray(One)` dynamic)?

Comment: I didnt get your point please answer it through changing code

Comment: you need to use the value as an index into an array, not using ifs. e.g. `pictures[labels[(x,y)]][y][x] = int(255)`, etc.

Comment: @corley-brigman can you answer with edited code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to name everything 'zeroth', 'first', 'second' etc, why dont you just name the file name _1.png, _2.png, ... , _31.png instead? It allows you to make the code much simpler.

```
temp=np.zeros(shape=(100, 100),dtype=np.uint8)  
for count, (x, y) in enumerate(labels):
    component = uf.find(labels[(x, y)])
    labels[(x, y)] = component
        temp[y][x]=int(255)
        if count>32:
            temp_img = Image.fromarray(temp_img)
            temp_img.save(os.path.join(dirs, file_+'_' + str(labels[(x,y)]) +'.png'), 'png')
```

If that wont work, you could use an array or dictionary with all of the possibilities 'zeroth', 'first', 'second', ... , 'thirty-second' and then simply name the file using something like this:

```
temp.save(os.path.join(dirs, file_ + '_'+ name_arr[labels[(x,y)]] + '.png'), 'png')
```

Comment: fix your indentation

Comment: use `for count, (x, y) in enumerate(labels):` for the if and remove the counts and also the first `if` since it is not doing anything.

Comment: Fixed indention and added the enumerate. +1

Comment: `elif` gives error so i replaced it will `if` also where i should define `temp`

Comment: i forgot to change Image.fromarray(Zeroth) to Image.fromarray(temp_img)

Comment: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'temp_img' referenced before assignment` this error appeared

Comment: Could you explain exactly what you are trying to do with the code? I was just attempting to show you a way to save files without using an if statement for each file name. I didnt make any assumptions about what you were doing with the rest of the code.